# How do i make my timer go to two decimal places?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I was wondering if any one knows how to make this timer do only two decimal places. Currently it show up to 6 decimal places. I am making a timer that goes up starting from 0 to see how long it takes a player to complete a course. If you know how to make the timer also carry on when you die and transfer to the next scene that would be appreciated. Once again thanks.

Here's the code I used

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timeStart = 0;
    public Text textBox;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Second", 59);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Minute", 9);
        StartCoroutine("bekle1sn");
        textBox.text = timeStart.ToString();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        timeStart += Time.deltaTime;
        textBox.text = (timeStart).ToString("F2");
        textBox.enabled = true;
        textBox.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Minute") + ":" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Second").ToString();

    }
    IEnumerator bekle1sn()
    {

        for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt < 600; iCnt++)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); //Bekleme
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Second", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("sureSaniye") + 1);



            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Second") + 1 == 0)
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt(("Second"), 0);
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Minute", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Minute") + 1);

                if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Minute") + 1 == 0)
                {
                    // finish the screen  


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To save time between scenes use [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently worked on such a project. mine was counting down from 10 minutes. you can edit this code yourself and transfer it to the next scene.

```
 string fmt = "00.##";
      start(){
          PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Second", 59);
          PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Minute", 9);
          StartCoroutine("bekle1sn");
        }

    void Update()
        {

                sureTextTMP.enabled = true;
                sureTextTMP.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Minute") + ":" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Second").ToString(fmt);

        }




IEnumerator bekle1sn()
    {

 for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt < 600; iCnt++)
        {
              yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); //Bekleme
             PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Second", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Second") - 1);



            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Second") - 1 == 0)
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt(("Second"), 59);
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Minute", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Minute") - 1);
                if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Minute") - 1 == 0)
                {
    // finish the screen  


                }
            }
           }
    }
```

Comment: I have added the code you gave me to my project and the code works but when running the game  it shows up as 9:1  or 9:59. So I was wondering if you could point me in the right direction. Ive added the new code on my question.

Comment: I added  the top line of the code so it will be 9:05 rather than 9:5

Comment: and after "line return new WaitForSeconds (1);" you should change the word "sureSecond" to second. stuck in my language :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings):

```
float f = 12.4435345f;
f.ToString("F2"); // 12.44
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formatting features of the String class like so:

```
textBox.text = (timeStart).ToString("F2");
```

This will round it to the 2 decimals that you require.

```
textBox.text = (timeStart).ToString("F0");
```

This would round it to a whole number